# Multiple device synchronization up to the millisecond

Tags: android

I have to start measuring sensor data across 4 identical android devices at the same time, What is the best way to do this?

I already have the data logging ready, I am just unsure on how to have all the devices start the function at the same time.  It is fairly important that all of the devices start measuring data within 100 ms, is that even possible?  I know android is not an RTOS.

Answer (score 0):

Have all the android devices keep UTC time inside the program that synchronizes with a trusted time server. Create a database somewhere on the cloud and have one device decide the exact millisecond to start the task.  Each device can then check in saying: "ready" or "not ready".  When all are ready, fire off the task at the appointed millisecond.

Comment: due to clock drift and network delay it is pretty hard to reliably synchronize with 100 ms precision